# Gradle could not find retrofit dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, retrofit2

I need some retrofit2 dependencies for my java project.
In build.gradle additional repositories are declared:

```
repositories
    {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
```

In dependencies section I declared:

```
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
```

So Gradle could not find them.
I used project-report plugin to analyze dependency tree. I got next report:

[image]

Interesting thing that before I used 2.0.2 versions for retrofit libraries and Gradle found them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Gradle version 2.12

Comment: The same configuration works for me. Could you give us an output of `gradle build -i --refresh-dependencies`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. After manually refreshing IDEA eventually saw loaded dependencies. I think the problem was with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @rvit34 could you please consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks

Comment: @InjuredThePatient Sorry, I cannot vote up for your answer now. I check it later and if it helps too I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

If using IntelliJ you can include plugin idea or include plugin eclipse, which gives you an option to run `gradle idea` or `gradle eclipseClasspath` tasks and refresh the project with updated/freshly added dependencies.

IDE's are not yet ideal supporting gradle.